# Android ImageView Fit_X Crop_Bottom

Tags: android, android-imageview

I need to work out the correct *scaling method* for the result below:

ImageView should be Scaled to:

- Fill the X axis
- Maintain aspect ratio
- Position ImageView at 0,0
- Crop the remainder at the bottom.

I have tried numerous `Matrix` types but have thus far failed to achieve the result.

Comment: did you try `center_crop`?

Comment: Center_Crop will evenly crop the Top and Bottom of the image. I need to only crop the bottom, as per the details above. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, my solution is that:

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    float imageWidth = image_original_width * display.density, imageHeight = image_original_height * display.density;
    float placeWidth = imageView.getWidth(), placeHeight = imageView.getHeight();
    float scaleToWidth = placeWidth / imageWidth;
    float scaledImageHeight = imageHeight * scaleToWidth;

    matrix.setScale(scaleToWidth, scaleToWidth);
    if (placeHeight > scaledImageHeight) {
        // there is maintain place bottom of image: center to vertical
        matrix.postTranslate(0, (placeHeight - scaledImageHeight) / 2);
    } else {
        // the bottom of image is already cropped
    }

    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

imageView.getWidth() won't you get right value in OnCreate method, so you need use ViewTreeObserver, or exact sizes.